# How do I find the sphere center from 3 points and radius?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

I have three 3D points p1, p2 and p3 and the sphere radius. How do I find the sphere center from 3 points and radius?

I expect two 3D points as solution because there are 2 spheres that meet the requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Find the plane P containing all three points. In that plane these
   points determine a triangle.
2. Find the circle around this triangle. Let C denote the center of
   this circle.
3. Find the line perpendicular to P and crossing it at C.
4. On this line, find those 2 points with the desired distance from the
   circle.

I have ignored degenerate cases.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to formalize this. Here's one of them (basically the same as Ali suggested, but with more math): you want to find points

(a) equidistant from p1, p2, p3, with

(b) the distance being exactly R.

First off, find a center of the circumscribed circle as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle (see the part about "the circumcircle of a triangle embedded in d dimensions"):

```
p0 = cross(
    dot(p21, p21) * p31 - dot(p31, p31) * p21,
    n
) / 2 / dot(n, n) + p1,
```

with `p21=p2-p1`, `p31=p3-p1`, `n=cross(p21,p31)`.

The points from item (a) lie on a line that passes through this point, and is orthogonal to the plane containing p1, p2, p3, so its equation is

```
p(t) = p0 + n * t
```

Substitute this into

```
dist(p1, p)^2 = dot(p - p1, p - p1) = R^2
```

to get the quadratic equation

```
dot(n, n) * t^2 - 2*dot(n, p0-p1) * t + dot(p0-p1, p0-p1) = R^2
```

Actually, `n` and `(p0-p1)` are orthogonal, so the second addend on the left is 0, and

```
t1 = sqrt((R^2 - dot(p0-p1, p0-p1))/ dot(n, n)),
t2 = -sqrt((R^2 - dot(p0-p1, p0-p1))/ dot(n, n))
```

(note how `p1` in `p0` cancels out). Substitute these into `p(t)` to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks , here is unity implementation if anyone guessing : https://pastebin.com/10qrh3Ta